# How to Continously Refresh a timer to Check a Background object value & Perform some Action depending on object state

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer, mvp

I Need a Continously Refreshing timer to Check a Background object value (after say every 10 seconds) & Perform some Action depending on object state in a C# Winforms application.

I'm a little confused between using `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`.

Also , I would appreciate if there is any other better solution available.

The first problem that I am facing is that I cant create the timer in the Initialize function block - it throws a run-time object reference exception.
So , i had to move it to the part where the `LoadData()` is being carried out.
(See Below).

So far , here is what I am Doing  :

```
//This function gets called only at initialize time
void Initialize()
{
//Initializing Commands , Context ,  base. ()_stuff etc goes here
}

//This function is called both when page is initialized first time
// as well as whenever Refresh button on the page is hit to reload the data
private void LoadData()
   {

    //Data Load Stuff Here

// My Timer goes Here


_poller = new System.Threading.Timer(o => RefreshStatus(), null, 10000, 10000);

       }  //End LoadData()
```

I have 4 questions that I would like answered :-

1) Which timer should i be using ?

(`System.Timers.Timer` OR `System.Threading.Timer` OR `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` OR Any Other).

2) Why am I not able to justify the same code in the Initialize() part that I am able to use in the LoadData() part?

Just FYI , I am using a loose interpretation of the MVP pattern

3) Since I am creating a new Instance of the Timer every time the page is loaded or reloaded or refreshed , do I need to worry about GC , by calling the dispose or deleting the previous instance of the timer or setting it to null ?

FYI, The _poller is a Class/Form level object.
I don't want a scenario where multiple timers start running in the same Form/page.

4) Wherever I have read about the Timer Best Practice usage , they have all advocated using an Infinite Timeout in the beginning and later updating it to a user desired value.
What is the specific advantage of this ?
Also , once I am done loading the data , I don't have a fixed place from where I can set the timeout. What should I do in such a case ?

Comment: _"they have all advocated using an Infinite Timeout in the beginning and later updating it to a user desired value"_ - who says?  You could always start with it **disabled**; set the interval; then `Start()` it.

Comment: Doesn't it start automatically ? (I have observed that it does for me)
> => P.S. -> Like I said before , this page doesn't have any specific place apart from the Load block where I could change any of the properties of the Timer; they are all event based function calls , that may or may not get called depending on whether the events are fired. This means that theoretically , my Timer will not start until too late or may not start at all if the event I choose is not fired.

Comment: [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx) has an `Enabled` property.  The default is `false`.  Considering you are making a `WinForms` app you probably should use that.  The others don't require a message pump.